# What's the different of moving /var into a new partition between standard way and links?

Tags: centos, partition, var

I want to move `/var` into `/mnt/var` since `/mnt` is mount as a new big partition `/dev/xvdb1`.

```
[root@stepping-stone ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       20G  7.1G   12G  38% /
tmpfs           7.8G   16K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdb1       99G   23G   71G  25% /mnt
```

I did that by the following commands:

```
mv /var/ /mnt/
ln -fs /mnt/var/ /var
```

Then I found it seems there is standard way to do that: https://serverfault.com/a/703607

I don't see the side effects of my 'easy way'. Anyone who can help point the difference between those two methods? or maybe I missed sth?

Answer (score 1):

The side effect is that the OS needs to resolve the path to any file under `/var` twice when you are using a symlink. That is, it first reads from root directory that `/var` is under `/mnt/var`. Then it makes the next lookup under `/mnt/var` directory.

Furthermore, having a system directory under `/mnt` isn't compatible with Unix standards, and therefore some applications might break, when `/mnt` does not contain what they expect it to contain.

Comment: Can you give an example of what application would break under this case?

Comment: I don't know any particular examples.