# Swap partitions between /home and /var

Tags: centos, raid, partition, swap

I have a server with 2TB (Raid, 2x2TB), and this partition schema

```
/ => /dev/md2 - 20GB
/home => /dev/md3 - 1.8TB
```

This is a ISPConfig server, so we need many space in /var and almost nothing into /home, so i think that the best way to do this is put /home in /dev/md2 and /var into /dev/md3

My fstab is this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md2        /       ext4    errors=remount-ro       0       1
/dev/md3        /home   ext4    defaults        1       2
/dev/sda4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/sdb4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
```

Which is the best way to do this? I think move /home contents to /homeold, remove from fstab, umount and now copy from /homeold to /home, and then change /var name (i dont have enough space to do the copy), mount new /var and move content, is this correct?

Also, i need to stop all server services to avoid errors (mysql, apache, mongodb, named, etc), any fast way to do this? Or maybe i should restart in rescue mode to do this?

Maybe another way is a full change between / and /home, i mean, put / in /md3 and /home in md2, is this possible only by edit fstab and reboot?

Thank you sou much,

Comment: how big is `home` and `var` dirs? Run `du -hs /home/`  and `du -hs /var/` to see how bid they is.

Comment: Home is 1.7GB, and /var, 6.7GB. All new content are going to be placed in /var, because is a webserver and all sites are generated there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best friend in this case would `rsync`. Create directory
`/home/var`. Sync it with existing `/var` directory.

`rsync -avh /var/ /home/var/ --delete` [man rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

When initial sync is done, do the same with `/home` partition.

After that you get very little downtime. Stop all services, run again rsync.
Check if no files is begin used in var and home. `lsof | grep '/var'` and
the same for `/home`. Here has chance that some libs is used from
`/var/lib`. But that can be ignored.  Now you have 2 options.

Option 1. mount `/dev/md3` to /media/ and then symlink `/media/var` to `/var`

Option 2. move `/home` stuff to `/home_new` (except /home/var). then move
all from `/home/var` to /home/, then remount `/dev/md3` to `/var`, rename
`/home_new` to `/home`. Make changes in `fstab`. **Reboot server** to see
if all is working correctly.

I better like option 2. I also suggest You to add [LVM](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-lvm.html) to `/dev/md3`.
Hope You get idea.

Similar question:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131311/moving-var-home-to-separate-partition
2. [CentOS & moving /var to a new disk/partition](https://serverfault.com/questions/695350/centos-moving-var-to-a-new-disk-partition)

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for you support. I made everytihing and i opted for option two, but at server reboot, connection refused on SSH login. I go to rescue mode, check fstab and all appears to be right, /md2 is / and md3 is /var, i checked everything, mount partitions and all fine... do you have any idea what's going on? I dosn't have KVM on this server. Thanks!

Comment: maybe permission issue? do you have old `/var` directory? Can You see syslog and dmesg.log. Maybe there is some useful info.

Comment: Apparently rsync fails at some point, because some folders was missing from new var directory, like the /var/empt/sshd was missing and some others, so i made a cp from old /var to new and now all works fine, so thank you so much!