# Need to extend var partition

Tags: centos7, partition, raid1

My /var is full and need to extend its size. I tried different ways but could not succeed. Cent os 7 with two 1 TB HDD RAID 1 Configured. I have added 2 TB HDD to add space for /var.

```
**# output for fdisk -l**

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00023fda

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2101247     1049600   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         2101248   393244671   195571712   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0006cf87

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048     2101247     1049600   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2         2101248   393244671   195571712   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md127: 1074 MB, 1074724864 bytes, 2099072 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/md126: 200.1 GB, 200131215360 bytes, 390881280 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 200.1 GB, 200085078016 bytes, 390791168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 41 MB, 41943040 bytes, 81920 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

**# df -h**
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root  184G  174G     0 100% /
devtmpfs                 1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.9G  8.5M  1.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md127               976M  145M  764M  16% /boot
tmpfs                    370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=move+%2Fvar+

Answer (score 0):

@Iain: not really a duplicate of [Move /var to new set of disks](https://serverfault.com/questions/340014/move-var-to-new-set-of-disks).

You have a much bigger problem than merely `/var` being full. Your `/` is full and your machine will crash soon (if not already).

You do not seem to have a separate partition for `/var`. Your `/var` is part of your `/` (root) which is on `/dev/mapper/centos-root` using LVM. You need to extend the `/` and put `/var` on a separate partition.

It is a bit unclear, but a safe bet is that the LVM is on the RAID1 (2x1TB).

A possible solution (similar to a recent re-config I did):

1. Fail one of the RAID1 (`/dev/md127`) elements (say `/dev/sdc2`)
2. Partition `/dev/sdb` (2 TB) into 2 equal parts of 1 TB each. Ensure that at least 1 partition is at least `195571712` blocks large (size of existing `/dev/sdc2`). Tag these partitions to be  of type `fd`
3. Replace the failed `/dev/md127` (old `/dev/sdc2`) with the appropriate `/dev/sdb` partition (say `/dev/sdb1`). Array will start to rebuild.
4. Create a new array say `/dev/md125` containing `/dev/sdc2` & `/dev/sdb2`. Owing to the fact that there is data on `/dev/sdc2`, this array will attempt to re-build. Let it be - AFAIK, you cannot stop it. Wait for a few hours for the array builds to complete. It is possible that you may have to reboot between steps 3 & 4.
5. Create a LVM2 physical volume using `pvcreate` on `/dev/md125` & grow 
   the `centos` VG on it (using `vgextend`). Using `lvextend` increase the size of the `centos-root` logical volume (to say another 100GB or so) and that will take care of your immediate problem. Use the `-r` (resize filesystem) flag to resize the underlying filesystem.

For the long term, you want to move your `/var` to a different partition. For that create a `var` logical volume (of say 100 GB or so), boot into single user mode or *better* use a rescue disk (to mitigate the open files problem discussed in [Move /var to new set of disks](https://serverfault.com/questions/340014/move-var-to-new-set-of-disks)), copy the old `/var` to the new one (after mounting it temporarily), adjust `/etc/fstab` to mount the new `/var`. Reboot and you should be set.